# Richedit Append форматированного текста

Tags: delphi

Используя метод `LoadFromStream` загружаю текст. Проблема в том, что он заменяет то, что было.

Можно ли как-то добавить текст к уже существующему?

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняй в **`TsringList`** что уже есть, после загрузки добавляй в **`StringList`** что загрузил в **`RichEdit`**, потом весь **`StringList`** загружай в **`RichEdit`**.

Или грузи с потока в **`StringList`** и уже оттуда добавляй в **`RichEdit`**.

В любом случае придется использовать посредник.

Comment: Первый вариант возвращает не форматированный текст, а второй вот:   
//////////
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\deff0\deflang1049{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset204 Tahoma;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\i\f0\fs22 erfhsdfghdfghdfgh\par
\par
}
//////////

Comment: поиграйся свойствами RichEdit второй вариант это и есть что Вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать richedit1.SelText+Text(ваша строка). Должно в точке курсора вставить текст из буфера или поля редактирования и т.д.